# Throw Database not found Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Is there a "built-in" Exception in .NET for **DatabaseNotFound** that I could use for a program that connects to a database server to perform maintenance tasks?

I feel there should be but I haven't been able to find it. In the code below you see that I check the existence of (defined in app.config) databases.

**XML file:**

```
<DatabaseConnection source="myLaptop" username="user" password="pass" defaultDatabase="DB1">
    <database companyIdentTable="tableA" companyIdentField="fieldA">Database_A</database>
    <database companyIdentTable="tableB" companyIdentField="fieldB">Database_B</database>
</DatabaseConnection>
```

**C# code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < appSettings.DatabaseConnection.database.Length; i++)
{
    string database = builder.QuoteIdentifier(appSettings.DatabaseConnection.database[i].Value); //Security measure
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name='" + database + "'", conn);
    if ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() <= 0)
    {
        Log("Database '" + appSettings.DatabaseConnection.database[i].Value + "' was not found. Service shutting down.", true);
        //TODO - throw a more specific exception!
        throw new Exception("Database '" + appSettings.DatabaseConnection.database[i].Value + "' was not found. Service shutting down.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest matches would be

- `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException`
- `System.Data.DataException`

Since your case is more likely a configuration error (invalid DB name specified) than the DB error (where database was not created successfully) the first option would be better.

If you want a specific exception, you should derive from one of these and create your own custom exception class.

Comment: ConfigurationException seems to be depricated. Think I'll go with DataException if no one else has a better suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: yes, the ConfigurationErrorsException is the one that MS recommends using.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) I would use [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx) since that is what [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) would throw.

Comment: the problem with `SqlException` is that whoever intercepts it will expect severity, state, and errors to be filled.